# export a large db with terabytes of data

Tags: database, mysql

what's the best way to dump a large(terabytes) db?  are there other faster/efficient way besides mysqldump?  this is intended to be zipped, unzipped, and then reimported into another mysql db on another server.

Comment: You can try using a client like [SQLyog](http://webyog.com/en/downloads.php). There's an option to backup the whole database into a zipped file directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's possible for you to stop the database server, the best way is probably for you to:

- Stop the database
- Do a file copy of the files (including appropriate transaction logs, etc) to a new file system.
- Restart the database.

Then move the copied files to the new server and bring up the database on top of the files. It's a bit complicated to do this, but it's by far the fastest way.

I used to be a DBA for a terabyte+ database in MySQL and this is one of the ways we'd do nightly backups of the database. `mysqldump` would've never worked for data that large. We'd stop the database each night and file copy the underlying files.

Comment: when you say mysqldump would never work for data that large, what do you mean? does it take too long or what?

Comment: `mysqldump` would take hours -- maybe 8-10 or more, maybe days -- to dumpt multiple terabytes of data. Also, if data is being inserted into the database during the `mysqldump`, then the resulting backup may not be consistent. `mysqldump` isn't practical for very large databases. The best option (not counting commercially available products) is disk snapshotting, followed by stopping the database and copying the files.

Answer (score 0):

Since your intent seems to be having two copies of the DB, why not set up replication to do this?

That will ensure that both copies of the DB remain in an identical state (in terms of data anyway).

And, if you want a snapshot to be exported, you can:

- wait for a quiet time.
- disable replication.
- back up the slave copy.
- re-enable replication.

Comment: Replicating a terabyte plus database will take a loong time.

Comment: Yes, so will taking the DB down for a file copy :-) The advantage of replication is that the DB remains active. And, once you've stabilised the two copies, the disable/backup/enable operation should be much faster and still without downtime.

Comment: @paxdiablo: my intent is to distribute a large database to clients, so it needs to be more portable, file copy probably won't work.